# Sum of primes: what is the problem in result?

Tags: c, loops, scope, initialization, primes

The code works fine but why are my answers wrong in the `int` result?

in output:

```
3
10
2 3 5 7: 17  //correct
30
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29: 146  //incorrect
50
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47: 474   //incorrect
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int y, n, i, fact, j, result = 0;
    scanf("%d", &y);
    for (int x = 1; x <= y; x++) {
        scanf("%d", &n);
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            fact = 0;
            for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
                if (i % j == 0)
                    fact++;
            }
            if (fact == 2) {
                result += i;
                printf("%d ", i);
            }
        }
        printf(": %d\n", result); //Not Getting correct answer please HELP!
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to initialize `result` before each calculation.

```
for(int x=1;x<=y;x++){
    scanf("%d", &n);
    result = 0; // add this for initialization
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        /* ... */
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `result` is initialized only once

```
int y, n, i, fact, j, result = 0;
```

So it will accumulate values calculated in the loop

```
for(int x=1;x<=y;x++){
   //...
}
```

Move the declaration of the variable `result` in the body of the loop

```
for(int x=1;x<=y;x++){
   int result = 0;
   //...
}
```

To avoid such an error you should declare variables in the minimum scope where they are used.

Also this loop

```
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0)
                fact++;
        }
```

does not make a great sense. Change the condition in the loop the following way

```
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0)
                fact++;
        }
```

substituting the variable `n` for the variable `i`.

Also you should use an unsigned integer type instead of the signed integer type int because prime numbers are defined for natural numbers.

The program can look for example the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned int n = 0;
    
    scanf( "%u", &n );
    
    while ( n-- )
    {
        unsigned int max_value = 0;
        
        scanf( "%u", &max_value );
        
        unsigned long long int sum = 0;
            
        for ( unsigned int i = 1; i <= max_value; i++ )
        {
            size_t count = 0;
                
            for ( unsigned int j = 1; j <= i; j++ )
            {
                if ( i % j == 0 ) ++count;  
            }
            
            if ( count == 2 )
            {
                printf( "%u ", i );
                sum += i;
            }
        }
        
        printf( ": %llu\n", sum );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

If to enter

```
3
10
20
100
```

then the output will be

```
2 3 5 7 : 17
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 : 77
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97 : 1060
```